# How to conditionally display a modal dialog in a knockout.js project?

Tags: knockout.js

A have a working form with a submit button from a knockout.js project. Among other things the form has a submit button.

```
 <form id="formAddNote" data-bind="submit: addNotes" role="form" style="z-index:1041">


     <button type="submit" class="btn" data-bind="enable: SubmitEnabled" style="margin- 
     left:-10px;">Save Note</button>
 </form>
```

Here is my knockout addNotes function that launches an ajax call to save the data to database:

```
 self.addNotes = function () {
     callAjax()

 }

 function callAjax(type, url, callback, data, errorCallback) {
    return $.ajax({
       type: type,
       url: url,
       dataType: 'json',
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       data: data,
       success: callback,
       error: errorCallback
   });
 }
```

Here is my modal dialog with a Cancel and Continue buttons:

```
 <div id="popUpModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button class="close" aria-hidden="true" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Existing RadConsult Found</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body"></div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Continue</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to add a step before the ajax call to display a modal dialog to inform the user if a note already exists and let the user select cancel to abort or continue to submit another note. How do I properly implement the dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 5 exposes a JavaScript API for modals that can be used to programmatically control the modal. Please see jsfiddle sample: https://jsfiddle.net/martlark/hxm83Lqo/18/. Example:

HTML:

```
<div id="popUpModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button class="close" aria-hidden="true" data-bind="click: clickCancel" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Existing RadConsult Found</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body"></div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-bind="click: clickCancel" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-bind="click: clickContinue">Continue</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<button data-bind="click: clickOpenDialog">
  Do the AJAX
</button>
<div data-bind="visible: mode()=='continue'">
  Continue clicked
</div>
<div data-bind="visible: mode()=='cancel'">
  Cancel clicked
</div>
```

ViewModel:

```
class ViewModel {
  constructor() {
    this.mode = ko.observable('start');
    const options = {};
    this.myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('popUpModal'), options)
  }
  clickOpenDialog(evt) {
    this.mode('confirm');
    this.myModal.show()
  }
  clickContinue(evt) {
    this.mode('continue');
    this.myModal.hide()
  }
  clickCancel(evt) {
    this.mode('cancel');
    this.myModal.hide()
  }
}

viewModel = new ViewModel()
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**

You could give an id to the 'Continue' button and add an event listener to it.

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    <button id="btnContinue" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Continue</button>
</div>
```

In JavaScript:

```
self.addNotes = function (data, event) {
    modal.show(); //Open modal.

    return false; //Suppress submit
}

$("#btnContinue").on("click", function() {
    callAjax();
});
```

**Option 2**

You could handle the event "[hide.bs.modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/modal/#events)" of your modal and detect the pressed button by checking which element on page has focus.

```
self.addNotes = function (data, event) {
    modal.show(); //Open modal.

    return false; //Suppress submit
}

modal.on("hide.bs.modal", function(event) {
    var $activeElement = $(document.activeElement);
    if ($activeElement.text() === "Continue") {
        callAjax();
    }
});
```

In the example above the 'Continue' button is detected by its text. Alternatively, it could be button id, data-* attribute, etc..